# Websocket API not returning answers AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a very simple `Websocket API` hosted in AWS.
I am integrated this API with a `Lambda` function whose code is :

```py
import json


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(event)
    return {
        "isBase64Encoded": False,
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        "body": json.dumps(event)
    }
```

I have also added integration response for a two-way communication as stated in this [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-websocket-api-integration-responses.html)

Below is my test using `wscat` with the command : `wscat -c myapiendpoint`

[image: result]

As you can see, i am connected successfully and if i write an existing route from the `request.body.action` selection (`sendMessage`), there is no error but there is no output. If i write a wrong route (`test` that i have not created in the API Gateway console), i have got an error message.

I have also tried with more simple outputs from the function, none is working. I have finally wrote the above code as stated in this [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/malformed-502-api-gateway/?nc1=h_ls).

I simply want to be able to send back a custom message to the client (actually data from my database) when a route is called.
This is actually what i want also for the `$connect` and `$disconnect` routes.

Am i doing something wrong ?

EDIT :

Here is my API Gateway setup for the route :

[image]

Here is a screenshot about the permission of the Lambda. By the way, these are the permissions for all of my Lambdas (under HTTP APIs) that all work fine :

[image: permissions]

Comment: Is your lambda actually exectued, what do the lambda logs tell you, what do the api gateway logs tell you?

Comment: yes i have logs from the Lambda in CloudWatch and everything is fine. The ```body``` param of the ```event``` contains my {"action": "sendMessage", "data":"test"}. API Gateway seems to only be logging $disconnect event and show no errors. Do you me to show you the logs ? I will update the ```print``` of the Lambda in this case and update the question.

Comment: hi - you can use the logging module to debug this - all of your logging statement will go into cloudwatch log (better than a print)

Comment: thanks yes i will use it. So far it probably doesn't give more info to use logging than print, I was simply trying to make a minimal sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes and it’s probably your case, you have not deployed your changes to your WebSocket API.
This happened to me when i was using automated stage deployment with HTTP APIs and not with WebSocket APIs.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your Lambda function does not have permission to post message to API Gateway connections. Try giving your Lambda function permission for action `execute-api:ManageConnections` on the API Gateway resource.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please provide more details ? I can't find this permission when trying to add it to my lambda. 
Besides, i have added a screenshot of my current permissions that are working fine with HTTP APIs, and are the same for this Lambda.